# Passing Image from View Controller to UIview in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to pass the image from view controller to uiview that added as subview.here I put my code that how I added the subview from view controller.

```
let subviewArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AddVisitorView", owner: self, options: nil)
let filtersView : AddVisitorView = subviewArray[0] as AddVisitorView
            filtersView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.5);
 self.view.addSubview(filtersView)
```

Here is the image that I want to pass to UIview. UIview class should have some implementation to retrieve that image.So how to pass the image between them

```
 var finalImage :UIImage = UIImage(CIImage: outputImage)!
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a property on your subview class and listen to changes on that property

Have a look at this code

```
class View: UIView {
  var image: UIImage? {
    didSet {
      // do something with image
    }
  }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let subview: View = View()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }

  func getTheImage() {
    let finalImage = UIImage(...)
    subview.image = finalImage
  }

}
```